# Using a text file as parameters for batch file

Tags: list, batch-file, text

I have a list in a text file.
Using a batch file, I need to search for references of each item in the list.
I will need to be able to determine where the item is referenced.

Here is a what I have tried:

```
REM WINDOWS COMPILE FORMS 


cls 
@echo off
for %%f IN (LIST.TXT) do
findstr /m "$item_name$" *.* > $item_name_$ || results.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Found! logged files into results.txt
) else (
echo No matches found
)

pause
```

My problem is I cannot find a way to plug the item in my text list into the batch file.

Comment: Do you need a different file for each item (as it seems by the `>$item_name_$`) or a single file with all matches (as it seems by the `logged files into results.txt`), or both?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I will need different file for each item.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the results you want just using `findstr` command. Read `HELP FINDSTR` and then try

```
findstr /m /F:txt.lst "$item_name$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that the elements on the list can be used as file names

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f IN (LIST.TXT) do (
    findstr /m /l /c:"%%f" *.* > "%%f" 
)
```

For each element in the list, search the files for the element and output the list of files containing it to a file named as the element in the list